# Show More / Show Less within datecompare in coldfusion

Tags: css, coldfusion

I'd like to add a Show More/Less button to my query results. The problem is I have 255 entries in the DB but only want to show those within a specific start/end date. The code below gets me the proper story list within the comparison (29 records for 2019) but I'd like to show the first 9 then click the More/Less button to reveal the rest. (9 or 10 at a time would be optimal.)

I tried with CF but I'm average at best and completely illiterate in javascript and JQuery. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code I need it on:

```
  <cfquery name="GetNewsArchive" datasource="DATASOURCE">
        SELECT ID, ENTRY_TIME, START_DATE, END_DATE, STORY_TYPE, 
            AUTHOR, TITLE, TEASER, NEWS_STORY_TYPE, NEWS_TOP_STORY, 
PICTURE,
                NEWS_LINK_URL1, NEWS_LINK_URL2, NEWS_CAPTION, APPROVED, BREAKINGNEWS, SHORT_URL
                    FROM MAIN
                        WHERE NEWS_STORY_TYPE = 18
                            AND APPROVED = 1
                                ORDER BY START_DATE DESC
    </cfquery>

<cfoutput query="GetNewsArchive">
    <cfset StoryDate = #GetNewsArchive.entry_time#>
    <cfset StoryTime = #GetNewsArchive.entry_time#>
    <cfset todaydate = DateFormat(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")>
    <cfset todaytime = TimeFormat(now(),"HH:mm:ss")>
    <cfset todaysdate = "#todaydate# #todaytime#">
    <cfset startcomparison = datecompare(#GetNewsArchive.start_date#, todaysdate, "h")><!--- either -1 or 0 --->
    <cfset endcomparison = datecompare(#GetNewsArchive.end_date#, todaysdate, "h")><!--- gotta be a 1 --->
    <cfset Request.NewsArchiveID = GetNewsArchive.ID>

    <cfif startcomparison lte 0 and endcomparison lt 1>
        <!--- ***** reformats start date to more pleasing format ***** --->
        <cfset newstartdate=#dateformat(createodbcdate(GetNewsArchive.start_date), "dddd mmmm dd, yyyy")#>
        <cfset newstarttime=#timeformat(createodbctime(GetNewsArchive.start_date), "htt")#>
        <!--- ***** reformats end date to more pleasing format ***** --->
        <cfset newenddate=#dateformat(createodbcdate(GetNewsArchive.end_date), "m/d")#>
        <cfset newendtime=#timeformat(createodbctime(GetNewsArchive.end_date), "htt")#>


        <cfif newstartdate contains "#NewsArchivetartDate#">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">  
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center grow">
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-3 text-left">
                            <a href="/story/#GetNewsArchive.short_url#"><img src="/images_story/#GetNewsArchive.picture#" alt="[#GetNewsArchive.title#]" class="img-fluid"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-8 text-left">
                            <a href="/story/#GetNewsArchive.short_url#" class="shortmenu">#GetNewsArchive.title#</a>
                            <p>
                            #GetNewsArchive.teaser#
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <cfelse>    
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

I tried using this approach that I found by user "Leigh" but it broke on the date compare unless I add a "Top x" in the query... which defeats the purpose of the compare.

```
<cfoutput query="GetNewsArchive">
        <cfset StoryDate = #GetNewsArchive.entry_time#>
        <cfset StoryTime = #GetNewsArchive.entry_time#>
        <cfset todaydate = DateFormat(now(),"yyyy-mm-dd")>
        <cfset todaytime = TimeFormat(now(),"HH:mm:ss")>
        <cfset todaysdate = "#todaydate# #todaytime#">
        <cfset startcomparison = datecompare(#GetNewsArchive.start_date#, todaysdate, "h")><!--- either -1 or 0 --->
        <cfset endcomparison = datecompare(#GetNewsArchive.end_date#, todaysdate, "h")><!--- gotta be a 1 --->
        <cfset Request.NewsArchiveID = GetNewsArchive.ID>
        
        <cfif startcomparison lte 0 and endcomparison lt 1>
            <!--- ***** reformats start date to more pleasing format ***** --->
            <cfset newstartdate=#dateformat(createodbcdate(GetNewsArchive.start_date), "dddd mmmm dd, yyyy")#>
            <cfset newstarttime=#timeformat(createodbctime(GetNewsArchive.start_date), "htt")#>
            <!--- ***** reformats end date to more pleasing format ***** --->
            <cfset newenddate=#dateformat(createodbcdate(GetNewsArchive.end_date), "m/d")#>
            <cfset newendtime=#timeformat(createodbctime(GetNewsArchive.end_date), "htt")#>

            
            <cfif newstartdate contains "#NewsArchivetartDate#">
                <cfset hideAtRow = 9>
                <!--- start container for "show more" --->
                <cfif GetNewsArchive.currentRow eq hideAtRow >
                <div id="collapse-news" class="collapse-inline collapse">
                </cfif>

                <!--- assign classes based on current row number --->
                <cfset btnClass = currentRow gte hideAtRow ? "btn btn-news dropdown-toggle" : "btn">

                <div class="row justify-content-center hover_drop_down">
                    <div class="col-12 text-left">                              
                        <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3">  
                            <div class="container col-12"> 
                                <div class="row justify-content-center mt-3 grow">
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <a href="/story/#GetNewsArchive.short_url#"><img src="/images_story/#GetNewsArchive.picture#" alt="[#GetNewsArchive.title#]" class="img-fluid doubleBorderGreen"></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-8">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                            <div class="col-12 text-left">
                                                <a href="/story/#GetNewsArchive.short_url#" class="shortmenu">#GetNewsArchive.title#</a> 
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 text-left">
                                                #GetNewsArchive.teaser#
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--- on last row, close "show more" container if needed --->
                <cfif GetNewsArchive.currentRow eq GetNewsArchive.recordCount and GetNewsArchive.currentRow gte hideAtRow >
                </div>
                <button id="testButton" class="btn btn-kw-ml MoreLess" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="##collapse-news">More</button>
                </cfif>
            <cfelse>    
            </cfif>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: First observation - you say, "but only want to show those within a specific start/end date", but your query does not have a `where clause`.

Comment: Second observation - `dateformat()` and `timeformat()` return strings.  You are using those strings in another function, `datecompare`, which is designed to process date and datetime objects.  Since you say your code "broke on the date compare", that might be relevent.

Comment: Thank you, Dan for your response. Here's how it all works: I preload stories to show on a specific date. Let's say the 1st story runs on 12/01/20, the second on 12/02/20, etc. On 12/02 the 1st story gets archived and will show up in this list. I need to ONLY show the archived stories in the list. I set the date range in application.cfm. The reason I do the datecompare is due to having close to 300 stories in the DB rom different years (2018, 2019, etc.) I've looked into trying to add the datecompare directly into the query but was unable.

Comment: I've updated the post above to show the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have written suggests that your major focus is getting the `datecompare` function to do something it's not designed for.  This is preventing you from accomplishing your objective, which is to:

- show a small number of records, and
- allow the user to get more records

If I were trying to do that, I would use a date filter in my query, and pass a datetime variable in the url scope.  Step 1 is to establish a default value for that variable for the initial page load.

```
<cfparam name = "url.startdate" default = #now()#>
```

Step 2 is to run your query, using that variable

```
SELECT top 9 
ID, ENTRY_TIME, START_DATE, END_DATE, STORY_TYPE, 
            AUTHOR, TITLE, TEASER, NEWS_STORY_TYPE, NEWS_TOP_STORY, 
PICTURE,
                NEWS_LINK_URL1, NEWS_LINK_URL2, NEWS_CAPTION, APPROVED, BREAKINGNEWS, SHORT_URL
                    FROM MAIN
                        WHERE NEWS_STORY_TYPE = 18
                            AND APPROVED = 1
and start_date < <cfqueryparam cfsqltype = "cf_sql_timestamp" value = "#url.startdate#">
                                ORDER BY START_DATE DESC
    </cfquery>
```

Step 3 is to get the earliest start date from your query.

```
<cfset minStartDate = arraymin(GetNewsArchive['start_date'])>
```

Finally, use that variable in your anchor tag.

```
<a href="ThisPage.cfm?startdate=#minStartDate#">Show More</a>
```

This gives you the general idea.  It will require formatting of the url variable which I'll leave up to you.

Comment: Thank you Dan, for your help. Unfortunately it didn't give me the results I was looking for. I was able to figure it out, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset DateToday = Now()> 

  <cfquery name="GetNewsArchive" datasource="DATASOURCE">
        SELECT ID, ENTRY_TIME, START_DATE, END_DATE, STORY_TYPE, 
            AUTHOR, TITLE, TEASER, NEWS_STORY_TYPE, NEWS_TOP_STORY, PICTURE, NEWS_LINK_URL1, NEWS_LINK_URL2, NEWS_CAPTION, APPROVED, BREAKINGNEWS, SHORT_URL
                 FROM MAIN
                    WHERE NEWS_STORY_TYPE = 18
                       AND APPROVED = 1
                       AND START_DATE LIKE '%#REQUEST.NEWSTARTDATE#%'
                       AND START_DATE <= GETDATE()
                       AND END_DATE < #DateToday#
                         ORDER BY START_DATE DESC
    </cfquery>
```

Comment: 1. Doing a `LIKE` search on `start_date` is strange. 2. Is this supposed to be the solution? 3. What is this?